# Shortcode to output get_header not working

Tags: functions, shortcode, templates

I'm trying to create a shortcode that will output the contents of one of my template header files. I created the shortcode in my `functions.php` file

```
function zoo_header(){
  return 'test'.get_header('navbar');
}
add_shortcode('zoo-header', 'zoo_header');
```

And use it in my templates: `[zoo-header]` or `do_shortcode('[zoo-header]')`

However, the output of the shortcode is simply 'test'.
Why is the content of my header-navbar not showing up?

```
#header-navbar.php
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
  'theme_location' => 'right-menu',
  'container' => false,
  'menu_id' => 'navbar-right',
  'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'
)); ?>
<p>testing 123</p>
```

It's as if `get_header()` is not returning anything. I would expect at least the testing 123 to show up...

A little background: I have 2 headers that I need to show, and I wanted to give the template authors the option to choose between one or the other.
I also tried using the `get_template_part('header', 'navbar')` with no success.

Comment: Did you consider including your headers depending on post-formats or page templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
function my_header() {
    ob_start();
    include(get_template_directory() .'/file.php';
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode('include', 'my_header');
```

Comment: Thank you! Just for reference for others, the shortcode functions are supposed to return a string, and not generate any output.
The get_header and get_template_part functions outputs their content, so we need to create a buffer.

Great article here:
http://kovshenin.com/2013/get_template_part-within-shortcodes/